# What to use for routing thousands of subdomains in Azure?

Tags: azure, routes, url-routing

We have an application that we are hosting in multiple environments in Microsoft Azure. We want to route the traffic based on subdomains, like xxx.mydomain.com should go to the webapp that I have in North Europe and yyy.mydomain.com and zzz.mydomain.com should go to the webapp that I have in the East US.

I know it sounds like simple DNS, but it is more than that. Because:

- I need to be able to add or update entries dynamically using code so an API should be available for that.
- A normal DNS entry has a 24 hours time to live meaning that if I want to move my app from one environment to another, for up to 24 hours, users will hit both environments.
- I expect to have hundreds of thousands of subdomains. Azure DNS has a limit of 25,000 entries.

I've looked into Azure Traffic Manager. It doesn't seem to have an option for traffic based on subdomains.
Also, I've looked at Azure Application Gateway. It seems to be the correct choice and it supports API's, but I cannot find the limits for subdomains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the solution is Azure DNS, but you must get in touch with MSFT and ask if they can increase the number of subdomains in your case

Comment: This is an edge case so you should contact MS for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested, we've ended up using Azure DNS. We have contacted Microsoft and they confirmed that they can increase the quota to 500,000 which is more than enough for us. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the criteria, it seems you're looking for a load-balancer/proxy/application-delivery-controller solution that's controllable through an API. I'll add my 5 cents here, as we've just gone through very similar problem. However these are more of a suggestion to look for answers elsewhere then Azure.

**Azure**

Azure Traffic Manager or Azure Application Gateway have limits which you can't fit in. For example in Azure Application Gateway with 200 rules, you could potentially host only 200 HTTPS site, the moment you need to serve HTTP & HTTPS, you're limited to 100 sites per application gateway. You'd need to split your solution across multiple subscriptions in order to fit subscription wide limits. Also the application gateway API is a bit too convoluted for my liking.

Azure DNS is also a bit problematic, as DNS records can last up to 24 hours. You'd therefore loose the ability to switch/route traffic to a different origin instantly.

**Self-hosted**

You could look into more old school solutions, run HAProxy or Nginx and programmatically modify their configuration(text files) on the fly and reload the configuration. HAPRoxy also has a [socket "API"](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/management.html#9.2) that can simplify the configuration modification and reload for you.

There's also a new set of service mesh controllers such as [Kong](https://konghq.com/), which can run in the cloud natively and are meant for service mesh solutions, however Kong offers a simple API, where you could manage/route traffic easily.

**SaaS**

If you're into buying this as a Service, Edge Cloud providers such as Cloudflare, Fastly or others are indeed "one big proxy server" and it is possible to configure them programmatically to route traffic to different origins, it's what they do after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. It is very elaborate and useful. Which one did you use for your case and are you still happy with your decision? Any hidden drawbacks? :) 
(I've already upvoted )

Comment: We haven't yet gone to production but are planning to use Cloudflare, as we'll also be using their caching.

For the drawbacks and advantages ... well, there's the obvious ones in selecting self-hosted vs SaaS offerings. Control vs Operations/Maintanability, cost ... you name it. I would note that there's an extra question in where do you plan to do TLS termination and certificate management. Also how much logging, extensibility do you wish for in this middleware? Logging, authentication/authorization, request throttling etc.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Application Gateway is indeed perhaps one of the best options for your scenario.
As you already said, it has an api that you could use to dynamically add rules based on your subdomains.

The limits for Application Gateway only allow for 200 rules per gateway.
But you can have 1000 gateways per subscription so if you could chain the gateways, that will give you roughly 200.000 rules.
The Microsoft documentation doesn't show that you can request an increase in these limits but maybe if you ask really nice the might allow it.

Maybe this is not *the* answer to your question but it might be *an* answer.